# How much money can be gifted tax-free as "étrennes" (~Christmas/NY/BD gift)?

Tags: taxes, france, family, donation

The French tax authorities allow parents to give some money tax-free to their children around some special dates, such as Christmas, new year eve, the child's birthday or the child's success at some major exams (such money is referred to as [étrennes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A9trennes)). How much money can be gifted tax-free?

[latribune.fr](https://www.latribune.fr/vos-finances/impots/donation-succession/20091228trib000456688/etrennes-et-fiscalite-peuvent-faire-bon-menage.html) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20160320105343/http://www.latribune.fr/vos-finances/impots/donation-succession/20091228trib000456688/etrennes-et-fiscalite-peuvent-faire-bon-menage.html)) is very vague:

> son montant doit rester dans des proportions raisonnables, par rapport à l'occasion et en comparaison de vos moyens financiers et de votre patrimoine.

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=%0A%3E%20son%20montant%20doit%20rester%20dans%20des%20proportions%20raisonnables%2C%20par%20rapport%20%C3%A0%20l%27occasion%20et%20en%20comparaison%20de%20vos%20moyens%20financiers%20et%20de%20votre%20patrimoine.&op=translate):

> its amount must remain within reasonable proportions, in relation to the occasion and in comparison with your financial means and your assets.

I have no idea what within reasonable proportions mean. 0.1%? 1% 10%? etc. Do the French tax authorities give any clearer guidance? If not, are  there any legal cases that could give some hints?

Comment: “*Étrennes*” refers specifically to end of year/Christmas gifts, the relevant concept for tax purposes is “*présent d'usage*” (cf. the article you quoted). Searching that phrase yields some useful results, including [this](https://www.capital.fr/votre-argent/present-d-usage-1317692).

Comment: @Relaxed great information, thank you, you are welcome to convert your comment into an answer, as I see the link your have contains the answer

Comment: I don't think the question is very good, please remove the nonsense about “étrennes”.

Comment: @Relaxed done, sorry I have pretty much never used French for the past 10 years... Dead language to me. I was hoping your answer would state this to avoid others doing the same mistake. (I misused the term because of some autochthone misusing the term)

Comment: If that's the issue, you could simply avoid using rare words you are not sure you understand and read your own source(s) a little more carefully.

Comment: @Relaxed etrennes is not at all a rare word. Unlike présent d'usage. Also not my fault is my tabloid I quoted misleadingly says "Etrennes et fiscalité peuvent faire bon ménage" in the title.

Comment: You also need to read the article. And yes, "étrenne" has become a rare word, something someone who doesn't speak French confidently would never use.

Comment: @Relaxed Not worth arguing further.  Do you want to write the answer or shall I do it? no preference

Comment: I'd rather see fewer questions like this one, writing answers (especially if they get positive votes) keeps them around so I won't write an answer.

Comment: How are you responsible for paying taxes in France without having used the French language for the past 10 years?

Comment: @ThePhoton Presumably, the person giving the money is a French resident. If the money they give is not considered a “*présent d'usage*”, it could be counted as part of an inheritance and taxed accodingly. Gifts are treated similarly so as to make sure it's not possible to circumvent inheritance law and under French law (and unless there are other provisions in a tax treaty), an inheritance can be taxed if the deceased is a French resident, no matter who the beneficiary is.

Comment: There is also 15-year window for gifts to be counted against the tax-free allowance for inheritance so that money given now and considered a *don manuel* (i.e. not *présent d'usage*) would have an impact for quite some time. Franck might even considering the possibility he would go back in France during these 15 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Relaxed](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/11981/relaxed) pointed to a great article in the [comment section](https://archive.is/6CL2B), https://www.capital.fr/votre-argent/present-d-usage-1317692 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112000730/https://www.capital.fr/votre-argent/present-d-usage-1317692)):

> La valeur du présent d'usage ne doit pas non plus être disproportionnée par rapport aux revenus et au patrimoine du donateur. En pratique, **la jurisprudence constante considère que le montant du présent d'usage ne doit pas excéder 2% du patrimoine ni 2,5% du revenu annuel du donateur**. Dans le cas contraire, le présent d'usage serait requalifié par les juges et par l'Administration fiscale en donation ordinaire taxable.

[Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=%0ALa%20valeur%20du%20pr%C3%A9sent%20d%27usage%20ne%20doit%20pas%20non%20plus%20%C3%AAtre%20disproportionn%C3%A9e%20par%20rapport%20aux%20revenus%20et%20au%20patrimoine%20du%20donateur.%20En%20pratique%2C%20la%20jurisprudence%20constante%20consid%C3%A8re%20que%20le%20montant%20du%20pr%C3%A9sent%20d%27usage%20ne%20doit%20pas%20exc%C3%A9der%202%20%25%20du%20patrimoine%20ni%202%2C5%20%25%20du%20revenu%20annuel%20du%20donateur.%20Dans%20le%20cas%20contraire%2C%20le%20pr%C3%A9sent%20d%27usage%20serait%20requalifi%C3%A9%20par%20les%20juges%20et%20par%20l%27Administration%20fiscale%20en%20donation%20ordinaire%20taxable.&op=translate):

> The value of the present for use must not be disproportionate to the income and assets of the donor. In practice, **constant jurisprudence considers that the amount of the present of use should not exceed 2% of the patrimony nor 2.5% of the annual income of the donor**. Otherwise, the customary present would be reclassified by the judges and by the Tax Administration as an ordinary taxable donation.

Furthermore, [Relaxed](https://money.stackexchange.com/users/11981/relaxed) mentioned that:

> Étrennes” refers specifically to end of year/Christmas gifts, the relevant concept for tax purposes is “présent d'usage".